# alarmManager fires intent without waiting for specified time

Tags: java, android

am trying to start an intent at a specified time to turn on wifi but for some reason the alarm fires instantly. i call setAlarm with getTimeDifferenceas a parameter. i checked the log.e and time that getTimeDifference returns is accurate but it still triggers instantly

```
   public long getTimeDifference(){
    Date current = new Date();
    Date future = new Date();
    future.setHours(time.getCurrentHour());
    future.setMinutes(time.getCurrentMinute());
    if((future.getTime() - current.getTime()) < 0){
        future.setDate(future.getDate()+1);
    }
    return  future.getTime() - current.getTime();
}
public void setAlarm(long time){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Volume.this,RadioService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
            Volume.this, 0, intent, 0);
    String sd = "time is:" + time;
    Log.e("time dif", sd);
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RTC_WAKEUP` wants the actual time in UTC, not the difference.